# SEO domain advice: sol-spl.com vs sol-spanish.com

Tags: seo, domains, url, keywords

I'm taking Spanish lessons from a school that uses a domain name `sol-spl.com` (not the actual domain), where `sol` is the name of the company, and `spl` stands for "Spanish private lessons".

I was thinking that it might be much better for their search rankings if they used the domain `sol-spanish.com`, since every search for spanish lessons is going to use the keyword `spanish`, and `spl` isn't likely to be used.

Will switching domains like this likely have a positive impact on their search rankings, and is it a reasonable thing for me to advise them to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the most part, domain names have nothing to do with SEO with some extremely limited exception. If I were giving you SEO advice, I would say neither example you provided is good. I would recommend whole words. The advantage of a domain name made up of whole words would only be minor but better than the domain names you provided. This is because the days of ranking any site based in part upon the domain name has long gone. This was a foolish proposition by Google and they now realize that fact. What is most important is that the domain name is memorable, easy to pass along verbally, easy to type, catchy, and most importantly level sets expectation. It is more important for SEO that the domain name be functional from a human standpoint and not for any other reason. LearnSpanishNow.com would be much better. (My apologies to whoever may already own this domain name.)